# What happens when multiple request occurs in a @async annotated function?

Tags: java, asynchronous

if already a request is processing and a new request occurred at same time 
into a @async annotated function lets say:

```
  public String importData(ImportRequest requestBody)
    {



       File file = new File(path.toString() + "/" + 
       requestBody.getFileName() + ".xlsx");

       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);


            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                 saveDataFromFileToDb();

                 }

    }
```

if a file has 1000 rows and its still processing in background, and 
suddenly one more request arrives then what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It will kick off another thread trying to do the same. But you could configure a single-thread executor. Your task will still be executed twice, but not in parallel.

You are talking about Spring's [@Async](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) annotation, right?

Comment: Yup, talking about spring @Async annotation. how could i implement single-thread executor.